# why 500 Internal Server Error occurs?

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, vbscript, iis-6

Hi All,

Actually I have a web application build using classic asp and vb script, along with MS-Access 2003 hosted on IIS 6.0. It is running fine.

Now I have shifted it to on IIS 7.0 and database MS-Access 2003 to 2010.

The Login Page is running fine, and also it's easily get login when I try to login. But after login when I try to access some others pages through click a button, it shows error 500 Internal Server Error.

I have given security this application to the everyone level but still it is showing error.

I am using database through DSN. I can not say that there is any DSN configuration error or mistake I did, because login page is working fine which gets user id and password from my database.

What type of issue might be there?

Comment: Could you give a link to the actual site, or is an intranet site?

Comment: for some security issue I am unable to give this link.

Comment: Sorry, but it's really difficult to give an answer without any real clues.

Comment: You need to investigate the IIS log, the windows logs. Once you've looked at them you'll probably find some error messages. Post the relevant messages.

Comment: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied

/accountest/travelapp.asp, line 408                                                                  even I have given permission to the folder to everyone level hierarchically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.  Now I have given my Intepub\mailroot\pickup forder to appropriate permission.